# Tensorflow prediciton error, invalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]

Tags: python, tensorflow, base64, prediction

I trained a Tensorflow Ssd object-detection model using Google object-detection Api and i exported the trained model using the provided "export_inference_graph.py" script as "Saved_model.pb" file with "encoded_image_string_tensor" as input type, however when i tried to make prediction to the model, i got the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]
```

İ loaded the model into a graph as follow:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], saved_model_file)
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

And made the prediction as follow:

```
# Convert the image into base64 encoded string
img = Image.open(IMAGE_PATH)    
resized_img = img.resize((300, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
binary_io = io.BytesIO()
resized_img.save(binary_io, "JPEG")

bytes_string_image = base64.b64encode(binary_io.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")

# Define the input and output placeholder tensors
input_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('encoded_image_string_tensor:0')
tensor_dict = {}
for key in ['num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores', 'detection_classes']:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'
        tensor_dict[key] = graph.get_tensor_by_name(tensor_name)

# Finally, do the prediciton
output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict, feed_dict={
                           input_tensor: bytes_string_image})
```

Comment: What is the reason that you are converting to a base64 encoded string?

Comment: Because, i exported the trained model to has an input type as base64 encoded string.

Comment: Nevertheless, it seems to expect a jpg to decide itself in TF

Comment: İ did not get it. Can you further explain that?

Comment: İ tried to send jpg image as np array, but i got: "ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 853, 1280, 3) for Tensor 'encoded_image_string_tensor:0', which has shape '(?,)'"

Comment: sounds like a step in the right direction :) I don't know why its the wrong shape though

Comment: Yeah. İm now retraining the models. And i will choose image_tensor as the input type.

Comment: Makes sense, Great idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I was saving the image as bytes, but it needed to be a string.

So instead of this:

```
encoded = image.tobytes()
features = {
    'image/encoded': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[encoded])),
    ...
}
```

You need to do this:

```
encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1].tostring()
features = {
    'image/encoded': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[encoded])),
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems in creating TFRecords, only jpeg images are supported and no where in the documentation this is indicated! also when you try to use other types, it does not issue any warnings or doesn't through any exceptions and therefore people like me lose an immense amount of time debugging something that could be easily spotted and fixed in first place.
Anyway, converting all images to jpg solved this weird hellbound issue.

you can also check this issue:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13044

This program will pick out files that are not actually jpeg. Delete them then you are good to go.
"""
import imghdr
import cv2
import os
import glob

for folder in ['train', 'test']:
image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), ('images/' + folder))
print(image_path)
for file in glob.glob(image_path + '/*.jpg'):
image = cv2.imread(file)
file_type = imghdr.what(file)
if file_type != 'jpeg':
print(file + " - invalid - " + str(file_type))

## cv2.imwrite(file, image)

"""